# Phillips SAA7139 TV tuner card not working

Tags: tv-tuner

When I had windows 7 installed on my computer, My TV tuner card used to work fine after installing the drivers but on Ubuntu it is not working.
I have tried several Softwares to get it working but none helped.
Today I installed Me TV and when I open it, I get an error saying:

```
There are no DVB devices available
```

What can I do to get my Philips TV Tuner card working.
I have a PCI card and here is the output of `lspi` command:

```
04:00.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7130 Video Broadcast Decoder (rev 01)
```

Comment: Can you perhaps add more detail on the exact model? lspci in a terminal should be enough to get the information.

Comment: You can try installing the package linux-firmware-nonfree, this will install some drivers. If it does not work please post the output of `lsusb` if you have a usb card or `lspci` for a pci card, to get the excat device name.

Comment: I added the output of lspci command, I think the last line says about the TV Tuner cause I have a Philips TV Tuner card.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Saa713x_devices

I used to have a Kworld Xpert TV PVR7134 with the SAA7134-based tvtuner 
You will need to find card and tuner numbers , for my card it was `card=63` `tuner=56`.
I had to add these options to `/etc/modprobe.d/saa7134` with `echo "options saa7134 card=63 tuner=56" > /etc/modprobe.d/saa7134`

More to read:

- http://tvtime.sourceforge.net/problems.html#undetected my card:
- http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/SAA7134
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1567212

Comment: I didn't understand what do I do now, could you please extend you answer and show some instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `linux-firmware-nonfree`.

It has historically held a lot of drivers for TV cards and usb sticks.

Comment: Still getting the error "There are no DVB devices available"

Comment: You'll probably need to restart to have it detected (if this does add the right driver).

Comment: I did restart but, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to tell the make and model of the card, then you need to create a `modprobe.conf` file in the `/etc` folder manually, then run the command:

```
gksu nautilus
```

in the terminal and browse to the `/etc` folder, create an empty file, name it  `modprobe.conf` then paste the following code:

```
# sets tv card for both analogue and digital
options saa7134 tuner=39 card=116 gbuffers=4
```

The numbers after `tuner=` and `card=` are variable according to your model.

For more documentation look [here](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Saa713x_devices).

Then save the file, close the folder and restart, than install 'Tvtime' from the software centre but don't open it and run the following command first on the terminal:

```
tvtime-scanner
```

after completing the above scan open Tvtime from the Sound & Video menu